# Can I use jQuery with Node.js? Is it good pair?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Can I use jQuery with Node.js? Is it good pair?

What are drawbacks if paring these 2 technologies?

Comment: jQuery is a JS library, it works fine server side.

Comment: @thealexbaron Neither jQuery nor Node are *languages*..

Comment: Create all JavaScript solution with Node.js on server side and jQuery on client. Usually Node.js tutorials don't consider jQuery

Comment: The first part of your question has been answered already and the second part is subjective and is not a good fit for the Q/A format.

Comment: @AlexW: I won't comment about your latter point, but as for the first point, this question is asking about Node.js server-side and jQuery client-side; the question it was marked as a duplicate of is about jQuery running server-side on Node.js. The first part of his question has *not* been answered already.